Safe 4337 Module: cannot deploy deterministic-deployment-proxy due to low gas price
I'm trying to deploy contracts of module 4337 to the new evm compatible blockchain.
Deployment crashed on the stage of deployment of deterministic-deployment-proxy
The main point of the problem is that I can't deploy contracts using deterministicDeployment because in the gas price in our chain is more than 100 gwei, so deterministic-deployment-proxy cannot be deployed.
If the transaction is rebuilt for the required gas price, the deployer and proxy addresses change.
As far as I understand the deterministicDeployment flag is made to make the addresses of contracts at the first deployment in all chains the same.
If we deploy contracts without using deterministicDeployment can we add/integrate our chain into Safe wallet?
The same problem is with allowances module.
Looking forward to your reply, thank you in advance!

Yes, deploying contracts without using deterministicDeployment should still make it accessible to a local version of Safe Wallet. For official support you would have to make a Pull Request here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-modules-deployments
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
